# array is not modified via function when using Object.value()

Tags: javascript, arrays

I try to write a splice function without using `Array.prototype.splice()`

```
function splice(array, start, deleteCount) {
   var returnArray = [];
   while(deleteCount != 0) {
      returnArray[returnArray.length] = array[start];
      delete array[start];
      array = Object.values(array);
      deleteCount--;
   }
   console.log(array) // [1,2]
   return returnArray;
}
var array = [1,2,3,4]
splice(array,2,2);
console.log(array); // [1, 2, empty, 4]; -> wrong
```

It seems something is wrong with `Object.values()` but I can't explain. Can someone give me an answer why the array outside doesn't show `[1, 2]`?

Comment: Why would you want to do this, when `Array.prototype.splice` is built-in?

Comment: What is `Object.values` supposed to do on an array? Do you use it as an alternative to  `array.slice()`?

Comment: Hi PHPglue, I have done with map, forEach, filter but struggle with splice

Comment: I use Object.values to remove empty elements

Comment: Now to answer your question, what `Object.values` does is, loop of every key/property and return its value. Since you are deleting a value, it will be set to `undefined` by default. But this key still exists. Hence you are getting empty(`undefined`). You should loop and check if value is empty, ignore it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass array into slice using `splice(array,2,2)`, it passes the object that your array variable outside is pointing to. Now your `array` parameter within your `splice` function points to the same object. However, your code `array = Object.values(array);` creates a new object and assigns to your `array` parameter. Now your `array` parameter no longer points to the exact same object as the outer `array`. If you do a `console.log` right before, you will notice the value of `array` is `[1, 2, empty, 4]`. After this point that value is retained since the `array` parameter has lost contact with that object.

For a better understanding try out this code:

```
first = [1,2,3,4]
next =  Object.values(first);
console.log(next);  // [1,2,3,4]
next[2] = 9; 
console.log(next); // [1,2,9,4]
console.log(first); // still [1,2,3,4]
```